# How to make those 2 queries into only one query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I would like to make only one query with these 2 queries in mysql php :

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM amis WHERE par='".$_SESSION['membre_id']."' AND   statut='confirme' OR a='".$_SESSION['membre_id']."' AND statut='confirme' ";
```

And the second query which is selecting all locations from the table :

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM locations";
```

Comment: What relation is between the tables?

Answer (score 0):

if your columns count different, u can't use one query for this.

use UNION for test

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM amis WHERE par='".$_SESSION['membre_id']."' AND   statut='confirme' OR a='".$_SESSION['membre_id']."' AND statut='confirme' union SELECT * FROM locations";
```

Comment: I got this error :Invalid query: The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

Comment: u can't using this. when your table columns count is not equal